# Which machine learning algorithm to use for high dimensional matching?

Tags: machine-learning

Let say, I can define a person by 1000 different way, so  i have 1,000 features for a given person.

**PROBLEM:** How can I run machine learning algorithm to determine the best possible match, or closest/most similar person, given the 1,000 features?

I have attempted **Kmeans** but this appears to be more for 2 features, rather than high dimensions.

Comment: The simplest approach would be to calculate the similarity between the two persons i.e. calculating the distance between the feature vectors of both the persons. Assuming all the data is numerical, you might want to first normalise the entire dataset of features to avoid any bias and then calculate the cosine similarity coefficient between every pair of persons. The higher the similarity the more similar they are. You can also try other similarity metrics like L1 norm.

Comment: HI @Rohit so your idea would be: for every feature, make the data numerical (convert words to numbers and store their mapping), then for every person, compare the distance between the features. After gathering the distances for each feature, run the cosine similarity on every feature to determine the most related features. Once running those, I presume doing a calculation of total cosine similarities and determine which of the cosine similarities are most similar, to not just get which features are most similar but which people?

Comment: What's your definition for the similarity of two people?

Comment: I guess maximizing the number of features that two people share. 2 matches features would be less than 5 matched features, etc. If there are alternatives that that thinking that may help when optimizing a similarity algorithm, I'm very open to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically after some kind of [K Nearest Neighbors Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm).
Since your data has high dimension you should explore the following:

1. Dimensionality Reduction - You may have 1000 features but probably some of them are better than others. So it would be a wise move to apply some kind of [Dimensionality Reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction). Easiest and teh first point o start with would be [Principal Component Analysis (PCA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) which preserves ~90% of the data (Namely use enough Eigen Vectors which match 90% o the energy with their matching Eigen Values). I would assume you'll see a significant reduction from this.
2. Accelerated K Nearest Neighbors - There are many methods out there to accelerate the search of K-NN in high dimensional case. The [K D Tree Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) would be a good start for that.

Comment: PCA is in general a good suggestion in OPs case. But just for the record: It doesn't "preserve ~90% of the data" as you say. How much of the original variation / dimensionality of the data PCA can keep very much depends on the settings (to how many dimensions do you let PCA reduce your data) and your data itself.

Comment: @petezurich, I said apply PCA in a manner which preserve 90% of the data. When dealing with PCA it means take the vectors which spread 90% of the energy.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That makes sense. I misread your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

### Distance metrics

You can try to apply a distance metric (e.g. [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity#Definition)) directly.

### Supervised

If you know how similar the people are, you can try the following:

#### Neural networks, Approach #1

- Input: 2x the person feature vector (hence 2000 features)
- Output: 1 float (similarity of the two people)
- Scalability: Linear with the number of people

See [neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/) for a nice introduction and [Keras](https://keras.io/) for a simple framework

#### Neural networks, Approach #2

A more advanced approach is called metric learning.

- Input: the person feature vector (hence 2000 features)
- Output: k floats (you choose k, but it should be lower than 1000)

For training, you have to give the network first on person, store the result, then the second person, store the result, apply a distance metric of your choice (e.g. Euclidean distance) of the two results and then backpropagate the error.